# last minute change in interview schedule

Tags: interviewing

I have had an interview scheduled for over a week.  I was told it would take 3 hours by 2 people with the company. I received email that it was changed to 2 hours. It was late evening email.

I am curious if anyone feels like this has turned into a courtesy interview because they already selected someone?

Comment: Anything is possible and we would need to be mind-readers to know for sure. But it is very possible that an interviewer had enough of a calendar crunch that they were forced to cut down on the time allocated to the interview.

Comment: Show them your enthusiasms and able to adapt to sudden changes, by acknowledging their mail. This may create a good impression to them about your positive attitude, as I believe they shall have a concrete reason for doing so. Which you may find out during or after the interview sessions.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but isn't it more likely that something came up? Remember, most people during the interview process have a full-time job that rarely offers them "time off" to do interviews.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i suspect *you* are overthinking this

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the one that should do the third hour of the interview got sick. Or won the lottery. Or fled to Canada. Who knows.

If they had already selected someone esle, they would either run your interview the way it was planned, or cancel it alltogether. Changing the plan and still "wasting" the man hours to do it would not be in their best interest.

Just ask them in the interview.

Comment: nooooooooo! don't ask them in the interview! why waste time selling yourself, or working out if the company is what you want? Who cares why the interview was shortened?

Comment: In our case, interviews have gotten rearranged because of Production issues that could not be rescheduled for a more convenient time. If a candidate had reacted to the schedule change by asking reasons why etc., it would be an indicator to us that they might not be comfortable in our environment, which is very dynamic. I'm not saying that being bothered by schedule changes is a terrible sin, just that it would be something that is incompatible with the way our team has to operate (we have a lot of dependencies on things outside of our control).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more likely that they have an additional candidate they're interviewing besides you and needed each interview to be shorter in length.  I think it's in your best interest to be as flexible as possible - I recently had a scenario where the company I was interviewing with wanted me to meet three people for my second round of interviews, but all three couldn't meet on the same day, so I offered to come in on two days, back-to-back to get all the interviews done ASAP.  They thanked me for my flexibility and it paid off, because they offered me the job.  I imagine I left a good impression, which helped my case, even if they were considering others.